# glmnet package: "mgaussian" vs "gaussian" for $\alpha = 0$

Tags: r, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet

In multiresponse Gaussian family the objective function when $\alpha = 0$:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2n}||Y-XB||_F^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}||B||_F^2.
\end{align}

This can also mathematically solved as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2nk}||vec(Y)- (I \otimes X)vec(B)||_2^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}||vec(B)||_2^2.
\end{align*}
yielding the same solution. However, when I tried to do it using glmnet package the answers I got are different. Can anyone explain why it is?

```
require(glmnet)
set.seed(7)
n <- 100
p <- 5
k <- 2

X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol=p)
beta <- matrix(rnorm(p * k , 0, 1), ncol = k)
Y <- X %*% beta + matrix(rnorm(n * k), ncol=k)

Xnw <- diag(k) %x% X
Ynw <- c(Y)

sd_ynw <- sqrt(var(Ynw)*(200-1)/200)
fit_glmnet1 <- glmnet(X, Y/sd_ynw, alpha = 0, standardize = F, 
standardize.response = FALSE,
                  intercept = FALSE, 
                  thresh = 1e-20, lambda = c(1, 2, 3), family = "mgaussian")

fit_glmnet2 <- glmnet(Xnw, Ynw/sd_ynw, alpha=0, standardize = F, intercept = FALSE, 
                  thresh = 1e-20, lambda = c(1, 2, 3))
do.call('cbind', coef(fit_glmnet1, s = 1))[-1, ]
matrix(coef(fit_glmnet2, s = 1)[-1], 5, 2)

> do.call('cbind', coef(fit_glmnet1, s = 1))[-1, ]
5 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
             1          1
V1 -0.01826165 -0.3290432
V2 -0.09559630 -0.2715274
V3 -0.13507974 -0.1161845
V4  0.18951137 -0.3014415
V5 -0.09837942 -0.2702261
> matrix(coef(fit_glmnet2, s = 1)[-1], 5, 2)
             [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.005284682 -0.21435828
[2,] -0.063831599 -0.19521015
[3,] -0.091713598 -0.08387311
[4,]  0.124559675 -0.21271566
[5,] -0.068698728 -0.17432439
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a mistake in the comparison. We can't directly compare the same $\lambda$.

```
set.seed(7)
n <- 100
p <- 5
k <- 2

X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol=p)
beta <- matrix(rnorm(p * k , 0, 1), ncol = k)
Y <- X %*% beta + matrix(rnorm(n * k), ncol=k)

Xnw <- diag(k) %x% X
Ynw <- c(Y)

sd_ynw <- sqrt(var(Ynw)*(200-1)/200)
fit_glmnet1 <- glmnet(X, Y/sd_ynw, alpha = 0, standardize = F, standardize.response = FALSE,
                  intercept = FALSE, 
                  thresh = 1e-20, lambda = c(1, 2, 3, 4), family = "mgaussian")
solve(t(X) %*% X + 4*n*diag(p), t(X)%*%(Y/sd_ynw))
do.call('cbind', coef(fit_glmnet1, s = 4))[-1, ]

fit_glmnet2 <- glmnet(Xnw, Ynw/sd_ynw, alpha=0, standardize = F, intercept = FALSE, 
                  thresh = 1e-20, lambda = c(1, 2, 3), family = "gaussian")
matrix(solve(t(Xnw) %*%Xnw + 2*200 * diag(p*k), t(Xnw)%*%(Ynw/sd_ynw)), 5, 2)
matrix(coef(fit_glmnet2, s = 2)[-1], 5, 2)
```

Then the solutions are identical.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why did you insert the `solve` lines? They don't seem to influence anything. If you can't compare the same lambdas, then how to you change the lambdas? Both `glmnet` commands still use 1,2,3.

Comment: @amoeba I just included manual calculations of $B$. Both `glmnet` commands don't use the same set of lambda. There is an additional 4 in `fit_glmnet1`. The sample sizes are different in the two objective functions: one has $n$ and other has $n*k$. This needs to be taken into account to compare lambda.